# create assembly run time by using Reflection.Emit. in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, reflection.emit

I want to create an **assembly** at **run time** like this:

```
AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName("ImanAssembly");
AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(an.Name, an.Name + ".exe");
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("Product", TypeAttributes.Public);
FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField("ProName", typeof(string), FieldAttributes.Public);
Type t = tb.CreateType();
ab.Save(an.Name + ".exe");
```

But I get this error in last line of my code:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Update: i solve that by run VS as admin...but why i cant find my created assembly in bin folder???? where can i find it ?

Comment: Run your VS as admin.

Comment: thanks  @PowerStar it works...but i dont see my assembly in bin folder ... do you know where can i find it ?

Comment: I have answered for this question. Check it may be help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get out from access denied problem you have to run your VS as Admin.

Below line will decide the directory path to store the assemble.

```
AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
```

In this you can specify the directory as third parameter. If you are not specified then, it will assume current directory.

So now you can find your exe file in C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express

If you want to save it in you bin folder then use below line.

```
    AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save, Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

Comment: thanks ...i want to create a class by reflection.emit as my entity models in EntityFramwork CodeFirst ...which one of Reflection.Emit And CodeDOM is better to do this job in you view ?? @Power Star